# return temporary table from SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I wrote this stored procedure:

```
USE [FAB28]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spPLCIOFilter2]    Script Date: 12/06/2011 08:00:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spPLCIOFilter2]
(
    @filter1 VARCHAR(50) = '%',
    @filter2 VARCHAR(50) = '%',
    @slot VARCHAR(50) = '%' 
)
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #temp
    ( 
         "PLC RIO" char(20)
         ,SIGNAL varchar(6)
         ,RACK char(2)
         ,SLOT char(2)
         ,POINT char(2)
         ,"CARD" char(20)
         ,TAG char(30)
         ,PROJ char(10)
         ,"DESCRIPTION" char(100)
         ,"ADDRESS" varchar(22)
     )

    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT
       [PLC] "PLC RIO"
      ,[SIGNAL] SIGNAL
      ,[RACK] RACK
      ,[SLOT] SLOT
      ,[POINT] POINT
      ,[CARD] "CARD"
      ,[TAG] TAG
      ,[PROJ] PROJ
      ,[DESCRIPTION] "DESCRIPTION"
      ,[ADDRESS] "ADDRESS"
    FROM [FAB28].[dbo].[PLC_TAGS2]
    WHERE [PLC] <> ''
    and [PLC] LIKE '%' + @filter1 + '%'
    and [PLC] LIKE '%' + @filter2 + '%'
    and [SLOT] LIKE '%' + @slot + '%'
    ORDER BY [PLC],[RACK],[SLOT],[POINT]

END
```

I want to return the temporary table `#temp` and `return #temp` doesn't work. Also I want that the temp table will be dropped at the end of the function.

How can I do it?

Comment: In your code which you post you can directly use select statement , you never need temporary table in this stored procedure if u posted complete stored procedure here

Answer (score 2):

You would add:

```
select * from #temp
```

at the end of the procedure.

In your SP, the temporary table looks redundant.  You could just replace the `insert` statement with a `select` to return the data immediately.

Comment: you are write :-)
i'm doing it because i have problems getting the data this way to sqlDataSource in the ASP.NET web that i'm building.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return temp tables like this from stored procedures. You'd have to create the temp table first, call the proc, read the temp table afterwards: all on the same connection so it stays in scope

However, why not just SELECT in the stored proc and consume the result set normally? You don't need a temp table here

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spPLCIOFilter2]
(
    @filter1 VARCHAR(50) = '%',
    @filter2 VARCHAR(50) = '%',
    @slot VARCHAR(50) = '%' 
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
       [PLC] "PLC RIO"
      ,[SIGNAL] SIGNAL
      ,[RACK] RACK
      ,[SLOT] SLOT
      ,[POINT] POINT
      ,[CARD] "CARD"
      ,[TAG] TAG
      ,[PROJ] PROJ
      ,[DESCRIPTION] "DESCRIPTION"
      ,[ADDRESS] "ADDRESS"
    FROM [FAB28].[dbo].[PLC_TAGS2]
    WHERE [PLC] <> ''
    and [PLC] LIKE '%' + @filter1 + '%'
    and [PLC] LIKE '%' + @filter2 + '%'
    and [SLOT] LIKE '%' + @slot + '%'
    ORDER BY [PLC],[RACK],[SLOT],[POINT]
END
```

Comment: the [FAB28].[dbo].[PLC_TAGS2] is a View,
and for some reason the sqlDataSource in my ASP.NET web-site doing problems getting data from it, i get this error:
"there was an Error executing the query. please check the syntax of the command and if present, the types and values of the parameters and ensure they are correct. Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain value violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints"

, but do not have problems if it takes data from an ordinary table.

so i'm trying to baypass this problem by using a temporary table.

Comment: @user454558: it sounds like the data violates some constraints defined in your client code DataTable. Using a temp table probably won't help because the data will still have NULL where you expect no NULLs, or duplicates when you expect unique values etc

Comment: i tryied to copy all the data from the VIEW to an ordinary table and i had no problems retrieving the data from the table.

Comment: @user454558: If that worked, then you it means you didn't make the same call or have the same data.

Answer (score 0):

To the secondary part of your question - any temp tables created within a stored procedure are automatically dropped when the stored procedure finishes - you don't have to take any additional actions.